# How to configure IdentityOptions outside ConfigureServices?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-identity

I want to configure `ASP.NET Core Identity` based on settings which resides in database rather than `AppSetting.json` or hard coded values. Consequently, I'am eager to call following line of code outside of method `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`:

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(x => x.Password.RequireDigit = true);
```

This way of calling will allow me to initialize `DbContext` before trying to configure `Identity`.

Currently I'm using `services.BuildServiceProvider()` in the `ConfigureServices()` to access database values. This style has a huge disadvantage for me: It puts an extra initialization on the application's `DbContext` which is dirty and slow. In the other hand, `DbContext` is instantiated two times instead of one.

If I was able to call `services.Configure<IdentityOptions>()` outside the `ConfigureServices()`, for example in the `configure()` method, I would be able to configure `Identity` options based on database values without initializing `DbContext` twice.

Again, my question is how to configure `IdentityOptions` outside `ConfigureServices`?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The options pattern supports DI. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2#use-di-services-to-configure-options-1).

Comment: @KirkLarkin, I injected `IOptions<IdentityOptions>` to the `Configure()` method and, it seems to be working. Would mind to add this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with injecting `IOptions<IdentityOptions> options` to the `Configure()` method as what follows:

```
    public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IOptions<IdentityOptions> options)
    {
      options.Value.Password.RequireDigit = true;
      //rest of configurations...
    }
```

And it worked!

Thanks to @Kirk for the link.